# How do people distinguish "data" refers to traffic and "data" refers to content?

Tags: distance-expression

In Chinese, we call mobile phone data as traffic, and we call the content -- such as files, photos -- on the phone as data.

Scenario
Someone is playing my cell phone. I tell him,

> My data is important. Don't get them lost. (I mean don't delete my photos or files.)
>
> My data traffic is not imortant. I have a unlimited data-traffic plan, you can use it as you want.

But in English, people call data traffic as data. Then how do people distinguish them?

Comment: BTW, it's just "called", not "called as".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same way we distinguish any two meanings of a word. From the context.

First, although the Latin word "data" is plural, the English word is almost always singular, and non-countable.

There are two senses of data that are relevant. 1: digital information and 2: download allowance in a mobile phone contract.

In your first example, modified to  "My data is important to me. Don't delete anything". It is completely clear that "data means something that can be deleted or lost.  You can't delete the download allowance. There is no ambiguity.  Even so you could be clearer by saying "My files are important to me."

In the second example, corrected to "I have unlimited data, use as much as you want." the only possible meaning is "allowance in a mobile phone contract".  You can't have an unlimited amount of digital information on your phone. Again, there is no ambiguity.

It is hard to think of a situation in which there could actually be misunderstanding. And if there ever was doubt about the meaning of a phrase, there are always ways to rephrase.

> How much data do you have on your phone  (perhaps ambiguous)

Could be rephrased as either

> How much storage have you used on your phone

or

> What data plan are you on?

Depending on the meaning that is intended.